# CanvasJS code relies on for in loop and that's fragile

Tags: canvasjs

There are a few lines of code in Canvas JS relying on the for in loop, without the use of the hasOwnProperty inside the loop.

When some other library extends the array prototype, it breaks CanvasJS.

In v1.7.0 GA, line 2406:

```
    for (index in plotAreaElements) {
        plotAreaElements[index].render();
    }
```

If you have extended the array prototype with a, let's say, a function called  "first", the code above will try to invoke "render" on the first function, and that breaks CanvasJS.

Really bad.

Can anybody fix this?

Answer (score 0):

This was reported in the CanvasJS-forum and bug has been fixed. Please refer to this [link](http://canvasjs.com/forums/topic/canvajs-and-array-prototype-extension/) to get an internal build.